# How to return object with smallest value of specific field (function?) in foreach loop java

Tags: java, algorithm, oop, for-loop, foreach

I am trying to get the smallest value for an object 'Employee' from a for-each loop.

I create some employees;

```
// Create Employees
Employee Employee1 = new Employee(1, "Bradley", 0);
Employee Employee2 = new Employee(2, "Patrick", 0);
Employee Employee3 = new Employee(3, "Erin", 0);
Employee Employee4 = new Employee(4, "Jim", 0);
Employee Employee5 = new Employee(5, "Fredrick", 0);
```

The third argument is number of assigned contracts, which is 0 by default. My code then assigns some contracts and the number of assigned contracts is incremented etc. Then I create an array out of the above employees like so;

```
Employee[] employees = new Employee[] {Employee1, Employee2, Employee3, Employee4, Employee5};
```

I can print the amount of contracts assigned to each employee using the loop below;

```
for (Employee employee : employees) {
    System.out.println(employee.numberOfCurrentlyAssignedContracts);
}
```

I'm trying to return the employee with the smallest number of employee.numberOfCurrentlyAssignedContracts, but rather than returning the int value of it I want the whole employee object to be returned so I can call a separate function on it, EG:

employee(with smallest value of assigned contracts).assignContract - assigning the new contract to the employee with smallest number of currently assigned contracts. So basically, how do I get the for-each to return the employee rather than the int value of assigned contracts?

Any help would be thoroughly appreciated.

Regards,
B

---

What do I do when all three submitted answers work?! Thank-you. Additionally how could I return an employee at random if 2+ have the same min value, eg, 2 employees both 0 assigned contracts..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of a simple for-loop to find the employee with the minimum number of contracts like as shown below:

```
int minContract = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
Employee empMin = null;
for (Employee employee : employees) {
    if (employee.getNumberOfCurrentlyAssignedContracts() < minContract) {
        // swap min and employee if true
        empMin = employee;
        minContract = empMin.getNumberOfCurrentlyAssignedContracts();
    }
}
```

Now you have a reference to the employee object that has the minimum contracts:

```
System.out.println(empMin);
```

---

If you are on java-8 then you can simply do:

```
Employee empMin = Arrays.stream(employees)
                        .min((e1, e2) -> 
                                  e1.getNumberOfCurrentlyAssignedContracts() - 
                                  e2.getNumberOfCurrentlyAssignedContracts())
                        .get();
```

Comment: accepted, this is the solution I went with. Would it be possible for me to implement logic to select an employee at random if both have the same value of minimum assigned contracts.. eg: both 0?

Comment: Firstly, thank you. Yes, of course. You can look up generating Random numbers with a seed.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
Employee minEmployee = Arrays.stream(employees)
      .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Employee::getNumberOfCurrentlyAssignedContracts))
      .findFirst().get();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this

```
Employee ref = employees[0];
int min = ref.numberOfCurrentlyAssignedContracts;
for (Employee employee : employees) {
    if(min>employee.numberOfCurrentlyAssignedContracts){
         min = employee.numberOfCurrentlyAssignedContracts;
         ref = employee;
    }
}
```

Then do whatever you wanna do with `ref`

Of course it would be a lot easier to use an `ArrayList` instead

Answer (score 0):

Something like that should do the trick. After that all you have to do is just assign the contract to selected person.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
Employee employee1 = new Employee(1, "Bradley", 10);
Employee employee2 = new Employee(2, "Patrick", 70);
Employee employee3 = new Employee(3, "Erin", 50);
Employee employee4 = new Employee(4, "Jim", 4);
Employee employee5 = new Employee(5, "Fredrick", 8);

Employee[] employees = new Employee[] {employee1, employee2, employee3, employee4, employee5};
int employeeWithLeastContractsID = employees[0].getID();
int employeesWithLeastContractsTotal = employees[0].getContracts();;
for (Employee employee : employees) {
if(employee.getContracts() < employeesWithLeastContractsTotal){
    employeeWithLeastContractsID = employee.getID();
    employeesWithLeastContractsTotal = employee.getContracts();
}
}
System.out.println("Employee ID: "+employeeWithLeastContractsID + "\nEmployee contracts: "+employeesWithLeastContractsTotal);
}
```